# Basic Concept of Laravel Routing & Controlling without PHP knowledge

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to learn practical knowledge so i directly go to laravel but i did not undertstand Basic Concept of Laravel Routing & Controlling without PHP knowledge, but i find php route content but confuse not concepts is clear about routing did not found any concept. I want to learn on very simple way.

I try hard to find simple concept of routing with and without parameters.

Comment: Hi start learning PHP before learning Laravel, that's the way to go ...

Answer (score 0):

Routing in Laravel is simple ->
When HTTP request is coming to PHP application, for example:

```
GET /user/10 HTTP/1.1
```

FastCGI (or other servers) defines variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with path `/user/10`; Laravel has only one entry point (`index.php` in `public` dir.) and to distinguish between which function we should invoke, Laravel checks that given path matches to defined routes in `web.php` (or `api.php`) file. Then, in matched route, we have information about controllers (set of functions). The controller is needed to share responsibility, so as not to write everything in one file. Routing and Controllers make up a well-extensible architecture.